# Integración Mercado Pago Point a mi IOS app

Tags: mercadopago

Estamos intentando integrar el lector de tarjetas en nuestra solución para cobrar con *MercadoPago* usando *Point*.

¿Hay un *SDK* para leer la tarjeta con *Point*?

También vimos que el proveedor da un *SDK*: http://bbpos.com/files/bbproducts/9-ChipperMini2_leaflet_20160905.pdf

Answer (score 2):

No, actualmente Point sólo funciona con la APP de Mercado Pago

Comment: Te recomiendo de siempre usar la fecha concreta del estado de la información, como "actualmente ( enero 2017 ) solo funciona...". Aun que tu respuesta lleva sella de tiempo, es más fácil de consumir la información así de una.